# Qt android emailing

Tags: android, qt, email

Let's say I start with a Qt app that is built for android with only one pushButton in it. I would like to have a function be called when the button is pressed where it will:

1. open gmail (or maybe any other default mailing app in android if possible)
2. set the "to:" to be a specific email by default (which doesn't matter if it can be changed later, just to have a default that is none empty that I can set from inside the app)
3. set the title of the email (again from inside the app)
4. set the text inside the email from inside the app

so basically the user only needs to press send because data should be already gathered (survey ish thing) and it just has to be sent. Obviously if it is possible to not open this app and send the email directly it would be even better.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: For simple cases, you can compose a mailto: URL (also allows setting subject etc.) and use QDesktopServices::openUrl(). (I’ve seen encoding issues though, depending on Android version). For more complex use cases (e.g. attachments), you need to use native API.